# FusionCharts ColdFusion integration

Tags: javascript, pdf, coldfusion, display, fusioncharts

In exporting bar2d FusionCharts to PDF using ColdFusion 9, I am getting some display issues where it adds some black boxes in the ranges.

[There are weird black boxes showing up behind fusion charts. Why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O0LT.png)

The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
        var chart2 = new FusionCharts({
            id: 'Chart2',
            type: 'bar2d',
            renderAt: 'chartdiv2',
            width: '500',
            height: '80',
            dataFormat: 'xml',
            dataSource: ''
        })
        chart2.setXMLUrl("example.xml");
        chart2.render();
    });
</script>
```

The example.xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <chart numberSuffix="%" decimals="1">
    <set value="47.8431372549" label="Leads"/>
    <set value="51.0941176471" label="RMNTS"/>
</chart>
```

The boxes do not show up when you view the graph in regular browsers, but when it is printed to PDF, the boxes show up. Has anyone seen any similar issues?

Comment: Can you include the code showing how you are converting to PDF?

Comment: You can make use of **FusionCharts export feature** to export chart to PDF. Please check out [this documentation page to know more](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/exporting-charts/exporting-charts-as-image-and-pdf.html).